# How to bold some lines in a Microsoft Word table cell using PowerShell

Tags: microsoft-word, powershell

I am currently creating a PowerShell script to take in user's input and formatting it into a Microsoft Word document as output (referencing to https://learn-powershell.net/2015/01/24/creating-a-table-in-word-using-powershell/).

My script is able to output the user input to each respective cells of the table but I would to bold some lines in the cell and underline some of it.

Understand I am able to implement formatting to the entire cell but I would like to enquire how to implement it to certain lines in the cell?

Sample of code below:

```
$ContentCell = ''
$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$Word.Visible = $True
$Document = $Word.Documents.Add()
$Selection = $Word.Selection
$Table = $Selection.Tables.add(
    $Selection.Range,6,4,
    [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdDefaultTableBehavior]::wdWord9TableBehavior,
    [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdAutoFitBehavior]::wdAutoFitContent
)
##Header
$Table.cell(1,1).range.Bold=1
$Table.cell(1,1).range.text = 'S/N'
$Table.cell(1,2).range.Bold=1
$Table.cell(1,2).range.text = 'Content'
$Table.cell(2,1).range.text = '1'
$UserInput = Read-Host - Prompt 'Enter your header here'
$ContentCell = $UserInput
$UserInput = Read-Host - Prompt 'Enter your header here'
$ContentCell = $ContentCell + '

' +  $UserInput
$Table.cell(2,2).range.text = $ContentCell
```

Current Output:
[image: Current Output on Microsoft Document]
Expected Output:
[image: Expected Output on Microsoft Document]

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33946827/ms-word-select-text-inside-a-table-cell. It is about selecting single characters, but you could maybe use wdLine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are really close, on the two lines

```
$Table.cell(1,1).range.Bold=1
$Table.cell(1,2).range.Bold=1
```

Change the `=1` to `=$True`.

```
$Table.cell(1,1).range.Bold=$True
$Table.cell(1,2).range.Bold=$True
```

You will also need to add lines where you want to underline:

```
$Table.cell(1,1).range.Underline=$True
```

In case that doesn't fully get you what you need; Before the excellent "ImportExcel" module was created, I did something similar in Excel and the the string I used to make a cell bold was:

```
$Stats.Cells.Item("1","C").Font.Bold=$True
```

Hopefully it will be as simple as changing the `=1` to `=$True`, but if not, my Excel example may help get you the rest of the way.